# Android ignore the hosts (etc/hosts) when it's in LTE network?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, hosts

I use hosts to block some sites, which works in WIFI connections,

but when I am in LTE mobile network, these sites seems accessible, I thought somehow android ignore the hosts.

I am in Lineages OS 14.1 (android nougat)

anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Any VPN involved maybe? Not sure whether that's really relevant, but it's the first thing coming to mind.

Comment: This is most likely due to proxy enabled in your APN settings, you can try disabling the setting first and see if the hosts are still blocked.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Since that was the correct answer, would you mind posting it as an answer so the questioner can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested by OP, the issue was caused by proxy in APN settings.

Disabling proxy in APN settings (*which interferes with host blocking usually by ignoring the hosts file*) solved the issue.

Comment: thanks for your hint, I finally manage how to set up an APN without proxy, and problem solved. Didn't know had a default proxy there.